# Chrome error message in the language of Cthulhu?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

Recently Chrome started displaying very strange error messages when it cannot find a page. It's quite random, it doesn't always does it and it seems to only affect the bolded parts of the text.

If I check the code in the console, the page unscrambles itself although the letters are still randomly spaced out. Does anybody know what could be causing this? Is it a known bug?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried disabling any Chrome Extensions you might have? Article here on starting in Safe Mode http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/extensions_broke_your_browser_how_to_enter_safe_mo.php

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/423495/gibberish-when-printing-pdfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a corrupted font. Try reinstalling the affected font.

Answer (score 0):

The gibberish text could be due to Chrome's language settings. Click on **Chrome -> Settings -> Show advanced settings... -> Languages and spell-checker settings**. Select the language on the left pane, and click on `Display Google Chrome in this language` on the right pane, and click `OK` to apply the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Some folks have solved similar issues by **disabling Hardware Acceleration** in their Chrome settings.

Head to the URL `chrome://settings/?search=hardware` and **disable** the option labeled "Use hardware acceleration when available".

Then, **restart your browser.**

Worked for me when I was having the same problem.

---

**Here's an example of the problem I was having:**

[image: Here's an example of the problem I was having.]

---

**I turned this setting OFF to fix the problem:**

[image: Here's the setting that fixes the problem.]

---